# Jquery - the same click function for multiple elements with different id

Tags: jquery

I have cca 150 elements with the same name, except of the id. I need to bind the same click function to them. In the current code, the following gets generated 150 times, but I think there has to be more efficient way.

What would be the most efficient way to rewrite the following code?

```
<script>
    var jizda_1 = $('a#jizda_1');
    jizda_1.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        id = 1;
        $('#jizda_' + cisloJizdy + '.active').removeClass('active');
        cisloJizdy = 1;
        if ($(this).hasClass('closed')) { // uzavrena jizda
            generujPoziceUzavreneJizdy(cisloJizdy);

        } else {
            generujPoziceOtevreneJizdy(cisloJizdy);
        }
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('#detailZakaznika').hide();
        $('#tiskDokladu').addClass('disabled');
        $('#tiskUctenky').addClass('disabled');
    });
    var jizda_2 = $('a#jizda_2');
    jizda_2.click(function(e) {........
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Give them all the same class, and bind the handler to the class.

Comment: Refer to a class all 150 elements have and use $(this) to identify the one clicked.

Comment: I can't believe you could have gotten very far in any jQuery tutorial without seeing examples of using classes for this.

Answer (score 4):

I would change the HTML so the elements in question share a common class. Then:

```
$("a.the-class").click(...);
```

Within the click handler, use `this` (which will be the element clicked), either directly (it's the DOM element) or by wrapping it in a jQuery wrapper (`$(this)`), to refer to the specific element.

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/qenarefa/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/qenarefa/1/edit)

But you *can* select them by the common part of their `id` using the [attribute-starts-with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector:

```
$('a[id^=jizda_]').click(...);
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/qenarefa/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/qenarefa/2/edit)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[id^="jizda_"]').each(function (k, v) {
    $(this).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        id = k+1;
        $('#jizda_' + cisloJizdy + '.active').removeClass('active');
        cisloJizdy = k+1;
        if ($(this).hasClass('closed')) { // uzavrena jizda
            generujPoziceUzavreneJizdy(cisloJizdy);
        } else {
            generujPoziceOtevreneJizdy(cisloJizdy);
        }
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('#detailZakaznika').hide();
        $('#tiskDokladu').addClass('disabled');
        $('#tiskUctenky').addClass('disabled');
    });
});
```